# SQLite handling Real Number from Database SWIFT

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have the following code and database and not sure why I am getting the result I am

```
private func preLoadData() {
    
     var dbPinch: OpaquePointer?
     guard let databasePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Airports", ofType: "db") else {
            return
     }

     sqlite3_open(databasePath, &dbPinch)
            
     let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM airports"
            
     func query() {
                
         var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
              
         if sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbPinch, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
                    
            do {
                        
                while (sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
         
                   let queryResultCol4 = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 4)
                   airportObject.latitude_deg = Float(Int64(Int(bitPattern: queryResultCol4!)))
                   print("Latitude_Deg: \(airportObject.latitude_deg)")

          }
                        
                try backgroundContext.save()
                        
           } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
                    
                  
                
        } else {
             print("Could not executes")
           
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
      }
      query()
      sqlite3_close(dbPinch)
    }
```

My database is structure as such with the field latitude_deg being type REAL.
For example the data in record in question is -22.81290054

When I print to the console I get this: longitude_Deg: 1.40518e+14

Any ideas how to handle real values returned from SQL. I have this populating and object property of type Float.
@NSManaged public var latitude_deg: Float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it this way fro anyone interested

```
let queryResultCol5 = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 5)
airportObject.longitude_deg = Double(String(cString: queryResultCol5!)) ?? 0
print("longitude_Deg: \(String(describing: airportObject.longitude_deg))")
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I don't know swift and don't have any way to test this, but its Sqlite3 API seems to follow the C one very closely)

I suspect you should just be able to use:

```swift
airportObject.longitude_deg = sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, 4)
```

instead of jumping through all those hoops with converting strings.